# Doxygen: Hide external namespaces from namespace index

Tags: c++, doxygen

When I started using Doxygen in 1.9.3, external namespaces from tags would show in the namespace list, which I didn't want/think was necessarily appropriate. So, I expressed this concern and [it was resolved](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/9241) in 1.9.4.

However, I just updated to 1.9.7 and it seems like 1.9.6 added them back, just now with an "[external]" mark, yet again, I personally don't want them there.

[image]

I figure that since they are now explicitly categorized as external there might be a way to disable their inclusion via my Doxyfile; however, I'm not really seeing anything that suggests that's true.

The only loosely relevant configuration options I can see are:

- ALLEXTERNALS
- EXTERNAL_GROUPS
- EXTERNAL_PAGES

all of which I already have set to NO.

Anyone know how to disable the display of these namespaces? Or do I need to return to the issue tracker?

Comment: I had a quick look at it and it looks like it has to do with the fix for https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/9602 (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/commit/d30a0fcbe78fff25d54b83476e1b4b054ef5dc9b) so it should be carefully investigated what would be the best solution for both situations. Best to return to the issue tracker.

Comment: In the original issue it was for "D:\doxygen_bugs\_patches\issues\issues_9\issue_9241\retest" though the mentioned Qt Namespaces are documented. When leaving out the Qt tag files would solve this the issue or does this mean that there are other problems (in your project) e.g. references to Qt namespaces / classes that are not shown in the original issue (i.e. links that should be present)?

Comment: @albert Perhaps the original issue was poorly titled. I use Qt tags because I want any Qt classes I specifically mention in my documentation to have URL links in order to highlight the importance of understanding their usage when appropriate; however, the namespace index is more of a top-down view of the project and Qt's own namespaces are not pertinent to my projects, especially given that Qt' namespaces are seldom used directly in user code. Ultimately its a matter of tidiness/look. I want to be able to link to Qt docs at my discretion, with its namespaces not being one of those things.

Comment: ...continued. As shown in the picture, the selection that does appear is very random/chaotic seeming, not to mention they lack descriptions and even an explicitly "private" one appears (which is of course out of my control given I don't author the tags). IIRC most NS documentation for Qt is intended to be internal. Basically, it's ugly. It looks like an implementation detail that shouldn't be there in this case, despite there being some legitimate cases for external NS to appear. But for these project's I just want to turn that off.

Comment: You mention "even an explicitly "private" one appears ", which one is this? Is it the "QtAndroidPrivate" namespace?

Comment: Yes, though I am surprised to see documentation for that NS is available online so I guess in more niche cases it is intended for users. I thought maybe it was internal documentation that wasn't seen as such by doxygen since it was originally made by qdoc. But this further highlights the rest of my concern. My project is not useable on android and has nothing to do with it, that NS shows only because its part of Qt Core. Pretty much all of those NS are not relevant, so their inclusion seems random, haphazard, and distracting, despite knowing the technical reason for why they're there.

Comment: @albert Not trying to sound mean about it, I just want to be as clear as possible with my position and why I think it's a valuable option to hide external namespaces. More-or-less: I obviously don't have control over what a 3rd-party project puts in their tags. If I want *anything* from a tag file I have to include *everything* from a tag file, even if I think some isn't pertinent, like in this case. Doxygen already lets you de-emphasize elements from external tags with variables like EXTERNAL_PAGES, and I'd simply like to do the same with namespaces as well.

Comment: I don't see the comments as being mean at all, it is good to point out the point of views (nobody has all the wisdom). Indeed it is hard to control the external tag files, only thing one could do is to cut out parts of the tag file, for doxygen it is not possible to do something based on the name of a namespace (I think that the problem here lies also in the fact that there are no private namespaces, at least not as far  as I know), so the only thing possible would be the brute force by means of a setting. That said, maybe a setting `TAGS_EXCLUDE` might be useful.

Comment: Like `TAGS_EXCLUDE = namespace:QtAndroidPrivate` or something similar where a complete "compound" is ignored.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, technically there are no private NS, you just have to label them as such and leave them undocumented, though this one is, partially contributing to this situation. It would certainly be nice to have more granular control over what's included or not, but in the short term is the option to simply show no external namespaces in the index, coinciding with the other EXTERNAL_ config options considered too niche/weird? Doxygen is of course aware of which are external and which aren't. I imagine it's best to continue this in #10234 at the Doxyen repo. I will summarize there.